# Allowing for multiple modals in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, vue.js

Following the demo on the official site (http://vuejs.org/examples/modal.html)

I'm trying to set this up so that I can define multiple modal windows on a page, like this

http://jsfiddle.net/m2sv4at5/

But since `modals['foo']` and `modals['bar']` aren't defined, Vue is throwing warnings that it's getting invalid types being sent into the prop. As soon as I initialize the script with `false` for both, it works, but that requires me to hard-code those modal names into the script, which is what I don't want.

In jQuery I would do this by defining a data target and simply making sure that matches an element with the right ID and a class of `modal`, but I'm unsure how to do something similar in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a reference ID to the modal component using `v-ref` it will become available to the parent and you will be able set `show = true` by refering to that ID. If that sounds complicated :

```
<button id="show-show" @click="showModal('foo')">Show Foo</button>

<modal v-ref:foo>
  <h3 slot="header">Foo Header</h3>
</modal>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    showModal: function(name) {
      this.$refs[name].show = true;
    }
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2sv4at5/1/

[Child Component Refs](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs)

Comment: Maybe you can help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451971/how-can-i-display-modal-in-modal-on-vue-component